# use genymotion run react native android debug open http://10.0.3.2:8081/debugger-ui

Tags: android, react-native, genymotion

#### Describe

I run react native android in genymotions , when i open JS Debugging , Chrome op http://10.0.3.2:8081/debugger-ui not http://localhost:8081/debugger-ui/ , so the genymotion log can't connect debug , why is that ? how to fix it ?

#### Environment

- macOS: 10.13.3
- android: 6.0.0
- genymotion: 2.12.0
- react-native: 0.53.3

Comment: Isn't there already anything on that port?

Comment: @Andronicus yes, this port can't open in fact, my other app open  http://localhost:8081/debugger-ui/ default , but this app use react-native 0.53.3 open http://10.0.3.2:8081/debugger-ui

Answer (score 6):

Let's fix your problem. Please follow these steps:

- Open the app in the emulator
- Press `Ctrl + M` to open the Dev menu, then tap `Dev Settings`
- Choose `Debug server host & port for device`
- Modify value to `127.0.0.1:8081` or simply `localhost:8081` and now reload the app. You will now be able to debug.

PS: Some tutorial might have recommended you to install the Chrome extension to allow CORS, but it is not needed. The method above is simpler.